# Trouble adding Django-Assets / Webassets directory to look for assets.py files

Tags: python, django

Was looking for a Python package for Django to manage assets, using Sass to compile CSS, and also cache busting, and Django-Assets / Webassets was recommended. Having trouble getting it setup though with my directory structure.

By default it looks for `assets.py` in each installed app. I want to set it up so that it sits in the same directory as `settings.py` and compiles app specific assets from each app directory into `/static/js` and `/static/css`.

I have `django_assets` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. According to [the docs](https://django-assets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#django_assets.settings.ASSETS_MODULES) it looks like I needed to add this to `settings.py`:

```
ASSETS_MODULES = [
   'project_dir',
]
```

Or:

```
ASSETS_MODULES = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project_dir'),
]
```

Or:

```
ASSETS_MODULES = [
   PROJECT_ROOT
]
```

At any rate, it just returns `No asset bundles were found. If you are defining assets directly within your template, you want to use the --parse-templates option.`

Even moving the `assets.py` into one of the app directories, it is looking in `BASE_DIR/scripts` which is where I keep my `manage.py`. Again, changing `ASSETS_ROOT` doesn't really same to be doing anything.

```
~/portal-client

project_dir
    apps
        account
            templates
                account
                    login.html
            forms.py
            urls.py
            views.py
        home
            templates
                home
                    home.html
            urls.py
            views.py
        results
    assets.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
scripts
    manage.py
static
templates
    base.html
    footer.html
    title.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of quick notes, for `ASSETS_MODULES`, the key word is additional:

> django-assets will automatically look for `assets.py` files in each application, where you can register your bundles. **If you want additional** modules to be loaded, you can define this setting. It expects a list of importable modules:

i.e., we only use `ASSETS_MODULES` if we have `assets.py` files outside of any application.  In your case, we will only specify this if `project_dir` is not an `INSTALLED_APP`.

Second, when using `ASSETS_MODULES`, you specify a dotted module path, not a directory.  In your case, this would be `project_dir.assets` only if `project_dir` is not already part of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That cleared up where it is looking for `assets.py`. Still running into the issue with it looking in my `scripts` directory for files to compile. I edited my question... might warrant an entirely new question.

Comment: This does warrant an entirely new question.

Comment: Understood. New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664753/trouble-setting-up-directories-to-compile-from-in-django-assets-webassets