# Trouble setting-up directories to compile from in Django-Assets / Webassets

Tags: python, django

This is my current `assets.py` file:

```
from django_assets import Bundle, register

sass = Bundle(
    'build/main.sass',
    filters='sass',
    output='css/main.css'
)

register('sass', sass)
```

Now I run into an issue with it saying `Another bundle is already registered as "sass"`, but not seeing how to unregister it.

At any rate, I change `register('sass', sass)` to `register('sass_all', sass)` to get past the error. When I go to compile it is looking in my `scripts` directory where I keep `manage.py`. In `settings.py` I add:

```
ASSETS_ROOT = [
  'static',
]
```

Which just has look in `scripts/static` which doesn't exist.

Tried:

```
# This is already in settings.py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

# Added new line
ASSETS_ROOT = [
    STATICFILES_DIRS,
]
```

It generates a couple errors: `KeyError: 'directory'`, `OSError: The environment has no "directory" configured`, and `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'`. Really it is just one error that `directory` isn't defined, I think.

Read through [environment documentation](http://webassets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/environment.html) which is vague given my skill level. In `assets.py` adding `Environment` to `import` just says `Could not import in Environment`. Adding `Environment.directory('static')` results in `Environment is not defined`. Just `directory('static')` also results in `directory is not defined`. `env = Environment()` same thing. Tried adding `directory='/static'` to `sass = Bundle(...)` which just says `TypeError: got unexpected keyword argument 'directory'`.

Anyway, spent a few hours on it and stuck again. Documentation seems to indicate `directory` settings should go in `assets.py` and not `settings.py`, whereas `ASSETS_ROOT` should be going in `settings.py`.

Thanks again in advance!

```
~/portal-client

project_dir
    apps
        account
            templates
                account
                    login.html
            forms.py
            urls.py
            views.py
        home
            templates
                home
                    home.html
            urls.py
            views.py
        results
    assets.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
scripts
    manage.py
static
    build
        main.js
        main.sass
    css
        app.css 
        main.css
    js
        app.js
        main.js
    media
templates
    base.html
    footer.html
    title.html
```

Continuation from this question: [Trouble adding Django-Assets / Webassets directory to look for assets.py files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658048/trouble-adding-django-assets-webassets-directory-to-look-for-assets-py-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick point to note:

```
# This is already in settings.py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
# After this line STATICFILES_DIRS is `[ 'BASE_DIR/static' ]`

# Added new line
ASSETS_ROOT = [
    STATICFILES_DIRS,
]
# After this line, ASSETS_ROOT is `[ [ 'BASE_DIR/static' ] ]`
# i.e., an array of arrays 
# I think you actually wanted:
ASSETS_ROOT = STATICFILES_DIRS[0] 
# - or more explicitly -
ASSETS_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
```

That said many of these issues look like they are being caused by a fairly non-standard django structure (i.e., that your `manage.py` is in the `scripts` directory rather than in `BASE_DIR`).

Comment: Thanks again for the the third time on the subject! Working good and I got cache busting working too (not keen on it keeping every version, but at least it picks the latest, but I'll take what I can get at this point... the clutter is a subject for a different day). Onto actually getting into Django deeper!